# Bind or Command to get return and button to work

Tags: python, events, button, tkinter, command

I have a simple question about the `bind()` method and the `command` argument.
Usually, in a program, you can click on a button related to what you are doing to execute something or simply press the return key. 
In the code below, I tried to do the same and it does actually work. 
I was just asking myself if the line `bttn.bind('<Button-1>', search)` isn't a bit strange, as it relates the mouse click inside the button to the function, and not the pressing of the button itself.

At the beginning, I didn't want to include pressing the return key to execute the entry, and I had written `bttn = Button(wd, text='Search', bg='Light Green', command=search)`, but at that point the `search` function wasn't an event driven function and had no event argument.

As soon as I wanted to include the return key pressing to do the same job, I had (of course) to write the function with `(event)`, and thus use the `bind()` method for the mouse button as well.

Is this the *"best way"* to do it ? Or is there a more idiomatic way of doing it ?

Python3/Windows

```
from tkinter import *

def search(event):
    try:
        txtFile = open(str(entr.get()), 'r')
    except:
        entr.delete(0, END)
        entr.insert(0, "File can't be found")
    else:
        x = 0
        while 1:
            rd = txtFile.readline()
            if len(rd)> x:
                longest = rd
                x = len(rd)
            elif rd == '':
                break
        txtFile.close()
        entr.delete(0, END)
        entr.insert(0, longest)

#####MAIN#####

wd = Tk()
wd.title('Longest sentence searcher')
entr = Entry(wd, bg='White')
entr.grid(row=0, column=0)
entr.bind('<Return>', search)
bttn = Button(wd, text='Search', bg='Light Green')
bttn.grid(row=1, column =0)
bttn.bind('<Button-1>', search)

wd.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an entry.bind and a button do the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891865/how-to-get-an-entry-bind-and-a-button-do-the-same-thing)

Comment: The question you mention was asked two years after I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to share a function between a button and a binding is to make the event parameter optional, and to not depend on it. You can do that like this:

```
def search(event=None):
    ...

bttn = Button(..., command=search)
...
entr.bind('<Return>', search)
```

If you omit the `command` and rely on a bound event, you lose the built-in keyboard accessibility that Tkinter offers (you can tab to the button and press the space bar to click it).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know and is probably the best way of doing it. Thanks ! So when you add `*` before an argument, you make it optional right ?

Comment: If the event is an unused parameter, you can name it `_event` to prevent warnings in PyCharm.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use a lambda `entr.bind('<Return>', lambda event: search())`